# $f_n \rightarrow f \implies \sup_A |PA - P_nA| \rightarrow 0$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $P_n, P$ be distributions with densities $f_n, f$ respectively. If $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere then:

$$\sup_A |PA - P_nA| \leq \int|f(x) - f_n(x)| \mu(dx) \rightarrow0$$

But what justifies the last step? I am trying to construct a dominating function for $f_n$ but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g_+ := \max\{g, 0\}$ and $g_- = \max\{-g, 0\}$.

Because $f$ and $f_n$ are densities, we have $$0 = \int (f-f_n) \, d\mu = \int [(f-f_n)_+ - (f-f_n)_-] \, d\mu$$ and thus $\int (f-f_n)_+ \, d\mu = \int (f-f_n)_- \, d\mu$. So,
$$\int |f-f_n| \, d\mu = \int [(f-f_n)_+ + (f-f_n)_-]\,d\mu = 2 \int (f-f_n)_+ \, d\mu.$$

You can dominate $(f-f_n)_+$ by $f$ which is integrable.

---

More generally, [Scheffé's lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_Lemma) implies that the condition $\int |f_n| \, d\mu \to \int |f| \, d\mu$ (in addition to pointwise convergence $f_n \to f$) is sufficient to conclude $\int |f - f_n| \, d\mu \to 0$. Your question is a special case where $\int |f_n| \, d\mu = \int |f| \, d\mu$ for all $n$.

Comment: +1 love this answer :)